# AF_XDP: Set `SO_TIMESTAMP` not supported for `SO_XDP`: Protocol not available

Tags: c, linux, networking, timestamp, xdp-bpf

Why is setting `SO_TIMESTAMP` not supported for an `AF_XDP` socket? The user manual of my driver (`mlnx 5.0`) states that

> Incoming packets are time-stamped before they are distributed on the
>   PCI depending on the congestion in the PCI buffers.

To my knowledge, `before distributed on the PCI` means that there is no Linux Kernel involved (yet) - right?

I tried setting it like this:

```
int timestamp = SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_HARDWARE;
if(setsockopt(xsk_socket__fd(xsk_socket->xsk), SOL_XDP, SO_TIMESTAMP, (int*)&timestamp, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to set `SO_TIMESTAMP`: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return;
}
```

And get:

> Failed to set `SO_TIMESTAMP`: Protocol not available

I copied the definition of `SO_XDP` from `xsk.c` (https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/master/src/xsk.c):

```
#ifndef SOL_XDP
 #define SOL_XDP 283
#endif
```

I don't understand, why it is not supported...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical reason on why it is not implemented.

Indeed, it looks like it is on the To-Do list of the xdp development team.

Cite from [here](https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-project/blob/master/xdp-project.org#metadata-available-to-programs):

> ### Important medium-term tasks
>
> ...
>
> #### Metadata from hardware
>
> There are various hardware metadata items that would be useful for XDP programs to access, to reduce the amount of processing that needs to happen in eBPF. These include:
>
> - Checksum
> - Hash value
> - Flow designator
> - Higher-level protocol header offsets
> - **Timestamps**

It looks like this is on the To-Do since June 2019, so it probably doesn't have top priority, otherwise it would already be implemented.